# Replace line feed only found between ;" and ";

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to import a csv file into MS Access.
The csv file as a field with linefeeds in it.
When I try to import the file, The linefeeds messes all up.

I would like to replace the linefeeds that are in a field but not the linefeeds that delimit the records.

The delimiter of the csv file is ';'.
Text are in double quotes '"'.

If I open the file with Notepad++, it looks like this:

fieldName1;fieldName2;fieldName3;fieldName4**LF**
DataNumber1;"DataText2";"DataText3";DataNumber4**LF**
etc

"DataText3" is something like:
"name: John**LF**Email: John@domain.com**LF**PhoneNumber: 00000000"

If I could replace **LF** between ;" and "; by any set of caracter like '###', I would be able to import the file and handle the data.

I tried to match \n between ;" and "; using

```
   (?=;\"[^\n]+)\n(?=[^\n]+\";)
```

Comment: so you want to replace datatext3 with name: JohnLFEmail ? or datatext3 is "name: JohnLFEmail" ?

Comment: "DataText3" is "name: JohnLFEmail: John@domain.comLFPhoneNumber: 00000000"

Answer (score 0):

This regex should do the work:

```
("[^"]*?)\n([^"]*?)\n([^"]*?")
```

replace it with:

```
\1###\2###\3
```

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/mwleqp/1).

If the number of LF is the same in all strings, you can adjust the pattern for your particular case.

If the number of LF in the strings might vary, then assume there is only 1 LF in the string, and run the replacement until everything is fine.

Comment: The number of LF in the strings might vary. I tried this (;"[^"]*?)\n([^"]*?";) replaced by this \1### It works and I only have to run the replacement one time. It's beautiful! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to virolino, the answer is:

```
(;"[^"]*?)\n([^"]*?";)
```

replace by

```
\1###
```